# Gaussian Mixture Model performance with data outliers

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

> Given Gaussian Mixture Model for clustering of data with outliers.

Will the performance of it degrade with outliers or it will work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

It will degrade, but not as badly as k-means.

At the same time, is not as robust to noise as DBSCAN.

Comment: thanks @Anony-Mousse are outliers and noise same?

Comment: No. Noise is not necessarily rare. If you have a data set with 1 million uniform distributed points, I'd call that noise, but not outliers. But at the same time, outliers usually are noise, in the sense of not being part of the signal.

Comment: got the difference thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian Mixture Models can struggle when there are outliers in the data - as the standard formulations will attempt to ensure that all datapoints are modeled by the Gaussian mixtures.

A common approach to avoid this is to use a mixture of Gaussian and Uniform components, where the uniform component is for the outliers/noise. This is described in [Robust Factorization Methods Using a Gaussian/Uniform Mixture Model](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-008-0169-x) and [Maximum likelihood estimation of heterogeneous mixtures of Gaussian and uniform distributions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378375810003174), and more.